# Convert exponentials to decimal in ruby

Tags: ruby

**I have output like the following exponential numbers.**

6.0e-07

8.1e-07

1.1e-09

**But I want above numbers should be displayed like below**

0.00000060

0.00000081

0.0000000011

I mean in the form decimal format. I surfed in the net. I could not find any solution for this.

Is it possible in ruby?. if yes How to do that?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`BigDecimal#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s):

```
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal.new('6.0e-07').to_s('F') #=> "0.0000006"
BigDecimal.new('8.1e-07').to_s('F') #=> "0.00000081"
BigDecimal.new('1.1e-09').to_s('F') #=> "0.0000000011"
```

Comment: Stefan - Why string conversion? I dont need to convert it into string.

Comment: You can pass a float to [`BigDecimal::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new), e.g.: `BigDecimal.new(1.1e-09, 0)` or `BigDecimal.new(1.1e-09, 16)` (second argument is the number of significant digits)

Comment: 2.1.0 :020 > BigDecimal.new("6.4e-10").to_s('F')
 => "0.00000000064" 
2.1.0 :021 > BigDecimal.new("6.4e-10").to_s
 => "0.00000000064" 
Why should we add ('F'). Without F the answer is same

Comment: @Jsd `BigDecimal.new("6.4e-10").to_s` returns `"0.64E-9"` on my system. According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) *"The default format looks like 0.xxxxEnn."*

Answer (score 2):

Scientific notation is standard when the number is too large or too small to be displayed in a meaningful way.

The best way to present the numbers the way you'd prefer is using string [format controls](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-format):

```
'%.10f' % 8.1e-07
# => "0.0000008100"
```

If you don't like the trailing zeroes, you can always trim those off with something like `.sub(/0+$/, '')`, though being careful not to convert `0.0` to `0.`.

Comment: Hey, I don't want to specify any digits like this as you had 10. I dont want to specify digits. I want 0.00000060 instead 6.0e-07. I don't want to round off anything??

Comment: A double precision floating point number can only contain ~55 places anyway, so `'%.060f' % n` will handle pretty much anything. There's no built-in support for what you're asking for, though.